# Segfault when using std::function class member with compiler optimizations

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, c++17, gcc8

I have a quite simple code example which crashes when optimized with `-O2` under gcc 8.2.0

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename Container>
class Lambda_Expression
{
    using Lambda = std::function<T()>;
    const Lambda & _lambda;

public:
    Lambda_Expression(const Lambda & l) : _lambda(l) {}

    T operator[](const std::size_t i)
    {
        std::cerr << "inside expression [] " << i << std::endl;
        return _lambda();
    }
};

auto lambda = []() -> double
{
    return 1.0;
};

int main()
{
    int N = 10;
    std::vector<double> res(N, 0.0);

    double x = lambda();

    std::cerr << "before for loop " << x << std::endl;

    auto test_expression = Lambda_Expression<double, std::vector<double>>(lambda);

    for( int idx=0; idx<N; ++idx )
    {
        std::cerr << "loop " << idx << std::endl;
        double x = test_expression[idx];
    }
}
```

Using also `-std=c++17`, in case that makes a difference.

I get

```
before for loop 1
loop 0
inside expression [] 0
[1]    5288 segmentation fault  ./bench_lambdas
```

whereas I would expect the loop to run for 10 iterations. This segfault does not appear with optimization level less than 2.

The above example looks like fairly harmless code to me and as far as I know level 2 optimizations should not break correct code.

**Question:**
Is there undefined behaviour or incorrect code in my example or what might be the issue?

Comment: Passing a lambda to a `const std::function<...> &` parameter creates a temporary `std::function` on the spot, which is then destroyed at the end of the full expression.

Comment: std::function != lambda, it's a wrapper this a performance cost

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far I know, it's undefined behaviour.

The problem is that your class register the reference

```
// ..........V  reference !!!
const Lambda & _lambda;
```

of the argument of the constructor

```
Lambda_Expression(const Lambda & l) : _lambda(l) {}
```

that is a `std::function`

```
using Lambda = std::function<T()>;
```

But when you call the constructor with a lambda (as in `main()`)

```
auto test_expression = Lambda_Expression<double, std::vector<double>>(lambda);
```

you save in `_lambda` the reference to a temporary object because `lambda` isn't a `std::function` so it's created a **temporary** object, of type `std::function<double()>`, initialized with `lambda`.

So the problem: the reference to the temporary object become a dangling reference at the end of the construction of `test_expression` so, when you call `test_expression[idx]`, you use `_lambda` that is pointing (potentially) to garbage.

I suggest to avoid this sort of problems avoiding the reference part (make `_lambda` a regular member of type `std::function`

```
const Lambda _lambda;  // <-- no more reference
```

so you copy the temporary object)

But if you really want that `_lambda` is a reference to a `std::function`, you should write something as follows

```
std::function<double()>  f{lambda};

auto test_expression = Lambda_Expression<double, std::vector<double>>{f};
```

This way the constructor receive a reference to a `std::function` object (`f`) that survive to his call.